# Fail OmniSharp MSBuild ProjectManager

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, visual-studio-code, asp.net-core-3.0, omnisharp

Note: I already search other similar question related to OmniSharp issue, could not find proper solution.Intellisense of vs code c# not working. I uninstall the c# extension and install again but it can not resolve my issue.I also install previous version of csharp 1.15.2 but it does not work. I attach my log info

> My dotnet --info is as follow

```
.NET Core SDK (reflecting any global.json):
 Version:   3.0.100   
 Commit:    04339c3a26

Runtime Environment:    
 OS Name:     Windows   
 OS Version:  10.0.18362
 OS Platform: Windows   
 RID:         win10-x64
 Base Path:   C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\3.0.100\

Host (useful for support):
  Version: 3.0.0
  Commit:  7d57652f33

.NET Core SDKs installed:
  1.1.14 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
  3.0.100 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]

.NET Core runtimes installed:
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.1.13 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.All]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.1.13 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 3.0.0 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 1.0.16 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 1.1.13 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.1.13 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 3.0.0 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 3.0.0 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]

To install additional .NET Core runtimes or SDKs:
  https://aka.ms/dotnet-download
```

> My log is as follow

```
Starting OmniSharp server at 10/12/2019, 8:51:54 am
    Target: e:\Nebula Materials\Nebula\Nebula.sln

OmniSharp server started.
    Path: C:\Users\aliimran.MREMIND\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode.csharp-1.21.8\.omnisharp\1.34.8\OmniSharp.exe
    PID: 17160

[info]: OmniSharp.Stdio.Host
        Starting OmniSharp on Windows 6.2.9200.0 (x64)
[info]: OmniSharp.Services.DotNetCliService
        DotNetPath set to dotnet
[info]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.Discovery.MSBuildLocator
        Located 2 MSBuild instance(s)
            1: Visual Studio Community 2019 16.3.29411.108 - "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin"
            2: StandAlone 16.3 - "C:\Users\aliimran.MREMIND\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode.csharp-1.21.8\.omnisharp\1.34.8\.msbuild\Current\Bin"
[info]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.Discovery.MSBuildLocator
        Registered MSBuild instance: Visual Studio Community 2019 16.3.29411.108 - "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin"
[info]: OmniSharp.Cake.CakeProjectSystem
        Detecting Cake files in 'e:\Nebula Materials\Nebula'.
[info]: OmniSharp.Cake.CakeProjectSystem
        Could not find any Cake files
[info]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectSystem
        Detecting projects in 'e:\Nebula Materials\Nebula\Nebula.sln'.
[info]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectManager
        Queue project update for 'e:\Nebula Materials\Nebula\Nebula.csproj'
[info]: OmniSharp.Script.ScriptProjectSystem
        Detecting CSX files in 'e:\Nebula Materials\Nebula'.
[info]: OmniSharp.Script.ScriptProjectSystem
        Could not find any CSX files
[info]: OmniSharp.WorkspaceInitializer
        Invoking Workspace Options Provider: OmniSharp.Roslyn.CSharp.Services.CSharpFormattingWorkspaceOptionsProvider, Order: 0
[info]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectManager
        Loading project: e:\Nebula Materials\Nebula\Nebula.csproj
[info]: OmniSharp.WorkspaceInitializer
        Invoking Workspace Options Provider: OmniSharp.Roslyn.CSharp.Services.RenameWorkspaceOptionsProvider, Order: 100
[info]: OmniSharp.WorkspaceInitializer
        Invoking Workspace Options Provider: OmniSharp.Roslyn.CSharp.Services.EditorConfigWorkspaceOptionsProvider, Order: 200
[info]: OmniSharp.WorkspaceInitializer
        Configuration finished.
[info]: OmniSharp.Stdio.Host
        Omnisharp server running using Stdio at location 'e:\Nebula Materials\Nebula' on host 18328.
[warn]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectManager
        Failed to load project file 'e:\Nebula Materials\Nebula\Nebula.csproj'.
e:\Nebula Materials\Nebula\Nebula.csproj(1,1)
Microsoft.Build.Exceptions.InvalidProjectFileException: The imported project "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets" was not found. Confirm that the path in the <Import> declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk.  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin\Microsoft.Common.targets
   at Microsoft.Build.Shared.ProjectErrorUtilities.ThrowInvalidProject(String errorSubCategoryResourceName, IElementLocation elementLocation, String resourceName, Object[] args)
   at Microsoft.Build.Shared.ProjectErrorUtilities.ThrowInvalidProject[T1](IElementLocation elementLocation, String resourceName, T1 arg0)
   at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Evaluator`4.ExpandAndLoadImportsFromUnescapedImportExpression(String directoryOfImportingFile, ProjectImportElement importElement, String unescapedExpression, Boolean throwOnFileNotExistsError, List`1& imports)
   at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Evaluator`4.ExpandAndLoadImportsFromUnescapedImportExpressionConditioned(String directoryOfImportingFile, ProjectImportElement importElement, List`1& projects, SdkResult& sdkResult, Boolean throwOnFileNotExistsError)
   at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Evaluator`4.ExpandAndLoadImports(String directoryOfImportingFile, ProjectImportElement importElement, SdkResult& sdkResult)
   at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Evaluator`4.EvaluateImportElement(String directoryOfImportingFile, ProjectImportElement importElement)
   at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Evaluator`4.PerformDepthFirstPass(ProjectRootElement currentProjectOrImport)
   at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Evaluator`4.EvaluateImportElement(String directoryOfImportingFile, ProjectImportElement importElement)
   at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Evaluator`4.PerformDepthFirstPass(ProjectRootElement currentProjectOrImport)
   at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Evaluator`4.EvaluateImportElement(String directoryOfImportingFile, ProjectImportElement importElement)
   at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Evaluator`4.PerformDepthFirstPass(ProjectRootElement currentProjectOrImport)
   at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Evaluator`4.EvaluateImportElement(String directoryOfImportingFile, ProjectImportElement importElement)
   at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Evaluator`4.PerformDepthFirstPass(ProjectRootElement currentProjectOrImport)
   at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Evaluator`4.EvaluateImportElement(String directoryOfImportingFile, ProjectImportElement importElement)
   at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Evaluator`4.PerformDepthFirstPass(ProjectRootElement currentProjectOrImport)
   at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Evaluator`4.EvaluateImportElement(String directoryOfImportingFile, ProjectImportElement importElement)
   at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Evaluator`4.PerformDepthFirstPass(ProjectRootElement currentProjectOrImport)
   at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Evaluator`4.Evaluate(ILoggingService loggingService, BuildEventContext buildEventContext)
   at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Project.Reevaluate(ILoggingService loggingServiceForEvaluation, ProjectLoadSettings loadSettings, EvaluationContext evaluationContext)
   at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Project.ReevaluateIfNecessary(ILoggingService loggingServiceForEvaluation, ProjectLoadSettings loadSettings, EvaluationContext evaluationContext)
   at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Project.Initialize(IDictionary`2 globalProperties, String toolsVersion, String subToolsetVersion, ProjectLoadSettings loadSettings, EvaluationContext evaluationContext)
   at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Project..ctor(String projectFile, IDictionary`2 globalProperties, String toolsVersion, String subToolsetVersion, ProjectCollection projectCollection, ProjectLoadSettings loadSettings, EvaluationContext evaluationContext)
   at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.ProjectCollection.LoadProject(String fileName, IDictionary`2 globalProperties, String toolsVersion)
   at OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectLoader.EvaluateProjectFileCore(String filePath) in D:\a\1\s\src\OmniSharp.MSBuild\ProjectLoader.cs:line 129
   at OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectLoader.BuildProject(String filePath) in D:\a\1\s\src\OmniSharp.MSBuild\ProjectLoader.cs:line 72
   at OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectFile.ProjectFileInfo.Load(String filePath, ProjectIdInfo projectIdInfo, ProjectLoader loader) in D:\a\1\s\src\OmniSharp.MSBuild\ProjectFile\ProjectFileInfo.cs:line 98
   at OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectManager.LoadOrReloadProject(String projectFilePath, Func`1 loader) in D:\a\1\s\src\OmniSharp.MSBuild\ProjectManager.cs:line 308

[fail]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectManager
        Attempted to update project that is not loaded: e:\Nebula Materials\Nebula\Nebula.csproj
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case i have two dotnet core SDK. One form Visual studio 2019 and one from vs code. so first i uninstall the SDK from vs code and update my visual studio. This can resolve my issue.

> Steps

1. check single version of SDK install on your machine  SDK or Visual
2. studio update to latest version